# Can't terminate a nohup process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, script

I would like to send a SIGTERM signal to a nohup process, but this signal is completely ignored, only SIGKILL works, which is considered a bad choice to terminate a shell script. Do I have any options here or do I have to stick to SIGKILL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to take this to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm pretty sure `nohup` is not supposed to trap `SIGTERM`, [unless you happen to be using the 4.3 BSD version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/nohup.html#tag_04_95_18). Maybe the script itself is ignoring the signal?

Comment: so sigterm is masked as well, check for external executions inside your bash script and find which one is responsible, you may find an alternative solution

Comment: If the author of the program made it ignore SIGTERM, surely he will have documented a way to stop it.  Perhaps it really does want SIGKILL.  Without access to information about this particular program, we can only guess.

Comment: Did you try `SIGQUIT` (before `SIGKILL`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure nohup traps only SIGHUP and not SIGTERM.

If I remember correctly,  bash **ignores** all SIGTERM and SIGQUIT signals sent to it,  unless traps have been setup.  Look here to findout how to setup traps in your script: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html

You can verify it this is the problem by first starting your script without nohup, then send a SIGTERM to it and see if it is ignored.